# Octave/Matlab - Are all elements in the vector the same?

Tags: matlab, octave

**I need a way to test if all elements in a vector are the same**

In my script, I start with an empty vector and a function that appends elements to the vector. I do not know beforehand what value the function is going to give me. I iterate and append an element to the vector every iteration. The iteration is supposed to go on as long as each new element that is being appended is the same as the previous elements. Once the function returns a different value, the while loop is supposed to break.

Basically, what I need to do is to test if all elements in a vector are the same, in general, as the function returns different values. I have tried using strcmp, however, it gives me an error about dimension mismatches.

*Thanks in advance!* 
V.Vocor

Comment: If you do this in a loop, it is enough to check whether the new number is equal to the last one. All the previous ones have already been checked for equality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to test if a vector or array `x` contains *strictly* equal elements. Here are a few. Note that `(:)` is necessary only if dealing with an array of more than one dimension; for vectors you can remove that:

- `all(x(1)==x(:))`
- `max(x(:))==min(x(:))`
- `all(diff(x(:)))==0`
- `numel(unique(x(:)))==1`

If `x` is of `double` data type, it may be better to allow for some *tolerance*, say `tol = 1e-6`. Then:

- `all(abs(x(1)-x(:))<=tol)`
- `max(x(:))-min(x(:))<=tol`

Comment: So many alternatives.. nice +1 :)

Comment: I guess you left a typo on the fifth one. shouldn't it be `all(abs(x(1)-x(:)) <= tol)` ??

Comment: Also i have one other doubt, while using tolerance, comparing all values with `x(1)` might be inappropriate? because taking this example say the maximum allowed tolerance is `0.5`. then if the vector is `X = [1 1.4 0.6]` then the maximum difference becomes `0.8` while the condition still might evaluate to `true`?

Comment: I like `std(x) <= tol`.

Comment: `max(x(:))==min(x(:))` and `max(x(:))-min(x(:))<=tol` do not detect the presence of NaNs. Not that that was in the problem description... :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate and append a value to the vector on each iteration, and if you break the for loop once the value being appended is different from all the previous, then will you are also breaking once the return value is different from the previous.

So compare with your last element on the vector (not the whole vector), it is much more efficient. Even better, since appending to the end of a vector is a very costly operation (it requires the whole vector to be copied in memory), drop the vector and keep in memory only a scalar element. Like so:

```
n = uint32 (0);
current = init_value;
while (current == foo ())
  n++;
endwhile
```